# Guys, How can we add Tacotron to a python program, I have made an AI program and I would like for it have the voice of Tacotron VCTK p240

Tags: python, audio, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, voice

https://google.github.io/tacotron/publications/speaker_adaptation/
This is the link of the website where I found the VCTK p240 voice. Is there a way for me to access this voice using Tacotron and add to in my python program so if a provide it a text it could return me with a audio with VCTK p240 voice.